# How to remove \r using IFS?

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I am writing a code snippet like below:

```
while IFS=$': \r\t' read -r -u9 marker v; do
    case $marker in
        Release)
            export RELEASE=$v
            ;;
    esac
done 9< <(git show -s --format=%b)
```

But I see that `$v` still contains `\r`. From https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS, I read `A sequence of IFS whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter.` Shouldn't what I did remove the trailing `\r` from the lines?

Comment: I you have more than 2 fields in the input, the second and all subsequent fields go into `$v`, including the delimiters.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a clean way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Comment: pipe the `git` command to `tr -d '\r'` inside the process substitution then try your `IFS` without the `\r`

Comment: Are you sure this is running under bash? For some reason, zsh doesn't seem to trim carriage returns in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with using `tr` to remove the trailing `\r`. This was my final solution:

```
while IFS=$': \r\t' read -r -u9 marker v; do
    case $marker in
        Release)
            export RELEASE=$(echo $v | tr -d '\r\t')
            ;;
    esac
done 9< <(git show -s --format=%b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are formatting the output of `git show`, then use a `null` delimiter `%x00` in your git format string, that can never be captured in a shell variable:

```sh
while IFS=$': \t' read -r -u9 marker v
do
  case $marker in
    Release)
      export RELEASE="$v"
      ;;
  esac
done 9< <( git show -s --format='%b%x00' )
```

Comment: it is a workaround but does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

You can change `read` this way :

```
read -r -u9 marker v possibly_something_else;
```

so that $v will not contain \r